# Flutter decide between fingerprint and pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, localauthentication

I have to add local authentication to the **flutter app**. Found great solutions [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) which is easy to integrate.

```
authenticated = await auth.authenticate(
          localizedReason: 'Let OS determine authentication method',
          useErrorDialogs: true,
          stickyAuth: true,
          biometricOnly: false,

      );
```

Everything works cool, But the authentication asks only for **fingerprint**.

In my phone i have (*face id, fingerprint, pattern*) mostly i use pattern because Fingerprint works sometimes, sometimes not, maybe my phone was damaged or i don't know.

But i wanted to have an option to **decide between pattern and fingerprint**. Is it possible? if i turn off fingerprint then auth_local asks for pattern, and if it would be the end user, he won't get it, he simply won't be able to pass the authentication.

If it possible i would like to turn off biometric leaving only (pin,pattern,password) lite security, ideally to select between pattern or fingerprint.

Is there any solution, this makes to refuse from local_auth, Please Advice.

Comment: you can use `https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lock_screen`

Comment: Hi @Tologon  , Did you find any solution?